# How to plot high and low of a candle except for current bar?

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to plot the high and low of a higher time frame candle onto a smaller time frame but I'm running into some painting bugs.

[barstate funny painting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5clW.png)

I'd either want it to refresh the plot on every single candle or not plot the current candle until it finishes. I've tried using barstate.isrealtime ? 1 : 0 with an offset but it still plots imperfect. Either the offset is off due to the 1 : 0, or it doesn't refresh per candle.

1. Can the plot be refreshed per candle?
2. How do I not plot the current higher time frame candle until it has closed?

Thanks.

edit:
When I say current candle, I mean current higher time frame candle.

Comment: I think I solved it. I just put a lookahead=true with variable offset depending on timeframe selected. Something like this: H1Offset = (timeframe.period == '15') ? -4: (timeframe.period == '5') ? -12 : (timeframe.period == '1') ? -60 : 0

Comment: I made something like that indicator. Look for the study, `Visual Candlestick Blender`.